# Problemas com o rollback no Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estou fazendo a importação/migração de um banco de dados antigo de um site meu para um novo formato. Estou usando Transações nesta importação, conforme o código abaixo.

O problema é que quando eu gero um erro o rollback não esta sendo disparado. Por exemplo eu tenho 5 registros que serão incluídos em um lote dentro do begintransaction e tenho um erro no registro 3. A exceção é gerada tratada mas quando eu olho no banco os 3 registros foram incluídos mesmo o com o erro.

O que eu estou fazendo de errado. Obrigado

```
$erros = new Erros();
\DB::beginTransaction();
try {         
        $pesq = $original->whereIn('cod', $request->get('codigo'))->get();            
        foreach ($pesq as $valores) {                
            $temp = [
                'id' => $valores->codigo,
                'plano_id' => 0,                    
                'cliques' => $valores->qtd_cliques,                    
                'caracteristicas' => $valores->caracteristicas,                    
                'destaque' => ($valores->destaque == 0) ? 1 : 0,
                'imagem' => $valores->imagemDestaque,                    
                'created_at' => $valores->created_at,
                'updated_at' => $valores->updated_at,
                'deleted_at' => $valores->deleted_at,
            ];

            \DB::table('casas')->insert($temp);                

            if(strlen($valores->filme)>2){
                throw new \Exception('Este imóvel contém 1 video que deve ser incluído manualmente.');
            }
        }
        \DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
        \DB::rollback();
        $erros->setId($valores->codigo);
        $erros->setCodigo($e->getCode());
        $erros->setMensagem($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito tentar junto com o Dinaerte Neto do grupo Laravel Brasil do Facebook verificamos que o problema era que a tabela era do tipo MyISAM e parece que não suporta transações. Mudei para INODB e tudo certo.

Answer (score 0):

Para capturar as `exceptions`  geradas pelo banco utilize `\PDOException`, a `\Exception` não captura esse tipo de erro. Possivelmente como o erro não está sendo capturado a transação ocorre `normalmente`.

Dentro do seu `if` também está sendo gerada uma exceção, interrompendo assim o fluxo de execução do código, coloque um `DB::rollback()` naquele trecho também.

Comment: bom dia. OLha fiz isto e mesmo assim não esta funcionando. O erro esta sendo capturado sertinho sendo tratado nas linhas abaixo do rollback e exibido na view certinho. Mas o rollback não faz o serviço dele. Eu estou forçando o erro de chave duplicada no banco como exemplo. Ele capitura e exibe este erro formatado na tela certinho. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry.